# Selecting multiple checkbox inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

enter code hereI have a `CheckBox` inside a `GridView` template. When a `CheckBox` is checked, it should send a column value to a stored-procedure, and show the desired result in another `gridview`.
When two checkboxes are checked, the values of two columns should be displayed in the other gridview.

My problem is that clicking the second checkbox removes the value of first checkbox, and causes only the value of the second check box to be displayed in the other gridview.

```
 protected void ChkRule_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < gdYojnaDtl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            string yojnaNo = "";
            CheckBox chl = (CheckBox)gdYojnaDtl.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            //CheckBox chl = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (chl != null)
            {
                if (chl.Checked == true)
                {




                    int rowsNo = (Convert.ToInt16(chl.ToolTip) - 1); 
                    yojnaNo = ((Label)gdYojnaDtl.Rows[rowsNo].FindControl("lblYojnaNo")).Text;
                    sc.Add(yojnaNo);


                }

            }
        }

    foreach (string obj in sc)
    {

        objyojnadetail4.YojnaNo = obj;
        DataTable city = objyojnadetail4.Selectcity();
        gdCityDetail.DataSource = city;



        gdCityDetail.DataBind();

    }

}





 <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Scheme Code">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblYojnaNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Yojna_No")%>' />

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Scheme Name">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblYojnaName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Yojna_Name")%>' />

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assistant Name">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="lblAsstName" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("Asst_Name")%>' />

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select for City">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"  runat="server"    AutoPostBack="true" 
                  oncheckedchanged="ChkRule_CheckedChanged" 
                  ToolTip="<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %> "   CommandName="cbCity"/>





                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
```

Comment: Do you reload the `GridView` on postbacks from `Page_Load`? Use this: `if(!Page.IsPostBack) DataBindGrid();`.

Comment: @tim the data is not getting bind in the grid view by doing ur solution

Comment: It should work since `ViewState` is enabled by default. If you reload the grid on every postback you prevent events from being triggered and overwrite changed values(like `CheckBox.Checked`).

Comment: i cant post my code but ur solution is not working

Comment: @user1942107 Tim is right, you make some how DataBing and the Grid is renders it from beginning, or you have disable the view state. If you can not post your code, you can make a simple working example with the same problem on an empty page and post it here (with the same problem)

Comment: While saving the data are you deleting all the previous checked ones from the DB and add the new one? That would also be a reason for that behavior. Are you sure that deletes and inserts are correct? Is the data in the database correct?

Comment: i have posted the code if any one can help me

Comment: still waiting for more appropriate answer

Comment: I do not see any code that sets checkbox.Checked value after or during binding the grid. If you have such code please include it.

Comment: the code for checkbox checked is included  "if (chl.Checked == true)"

Answer (score 0):

```
//**This code is tested and working fine** 
//at aspx page
<columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Checkboxes">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="cheker" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

//this button is outside gridview but in same page
<asp:Button ID="check" runat="server" CssClass="btnstyle" Text="Check"       OnClick="btnredirect_Click" />
```

//method for click events in codebehind

```
protected void btnredirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    switch (btn.ID)
    {
        case "check":
            {
                for(int i=0;i<Gvshowcart.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox chl =     (CheckBox)Gvshowcart.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("cheker");
                    if (chl != null)
                    {
                        if (chl.Checked == true)
                        {
                            chl.Checked = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            chl.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            break;
    }
```

}